# How to add extra loop cuts without affecting subsurf

Tags: modeling, mesh, subdivision-surface

I'm trying to model an iPhone. I have made the base shape for the phone by using a cube with subsurf modifier. Im now trying to make a button on the side but I cant do this without adding loop cuts and this affects the shape of the phone due to subsurface. How can I make a button as seen in the picture to my model while keeping the rounded shape the same of the current model?[image: Hope this new image clears some things up. One on the right is with subsurf one on the left is without]

Comment: the button should be a separate mesh, but you need to make the hole for it. But actually you don't show your wireframe so it's hard to tell what to do...

Comment: @Pat, I think it would really make sense to add screenshots of the geometry with questions like that. How else will someone be able to help you without seeing what you are doing? I down-voted the question as it seems to me it is poorly formed without any pictures showing the topology and therefore not a very useful question.

Comment: Thats my bad ill edit the question asap

Comment: Thank you @moonboots, for the suggestion. Do u know how I cud do this? Using a boolean would be painful and not that effective I would have thought.

Comment: Please check, if any of [these](hole subsurf) are related to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add some geometry to your mesh. Then add some edge loops around with some bevels and <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, delete faces, extrude, move a bit the edge loops you've created to make the hole round, and extrude inwards. To make the button just duplicate the hole profile and extrude.

[image]

Comment: Thank you moonboots for the response. The only problem with this solution is that the curvature of the edges on the original model is not maintained. The iPhone X has very rounded edges and doing this method flattens out the sides. That was the tricky thing about my problem. Sorry if my original question was unclear.

Comment: Moonboots I’m not sure how to without sharpening the edges. This happens whenever I add loop cuts. Sorry for being such a noob. I’m new to modeling.

Comment: Ok I've edited, I think if your shape is rounder you need to add geometry

Comment: Thank you for your patience with me. I'm just starting out with modelling, I am unsure how to make the hole rounded. Thank you again for helping me out.

Comment: hello, what do you mean "rounded"? It will be as you have a Subsurf modifier, you just need to add some edge loops so that the angles stay sharp