# Everything looks great on camera, except when you turn on smooth shading

Tags: materials, shaders, normals

Everything looks great when modeled and looked at in flat shading, but when I get to exporting with a plugin it just look weird. What did i do wrong?

Flat shading (material preview)
[image: flat shading]

Smooth shading (solid view)
[image: smooth shading]

[image]

Comment: your face is made of a huge ngon, if the face is not completely flat it creates artifacts like this, you need to correct the topology

Comment: look at this kind of topologies: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139912/how-to-add-extra-loop-cuts-without-affecting-subsurf ... https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112612/how-to-dig-an-elliptical-hole-in-blender-iphone

Comment: @moonboots sorry to ask this but I am new to Blender. In one of the links you shared there is a mention of a sub surf modifier, which one is that?

Comment: Subdivision Surface modifier, it allows you to fake additional edge loops, therefore it makes the object rounder

Comment: I think I need to get back into tutorials... I did all the holes using the boolean modifier and I thing that's why all the ugly artifacts. Just so I avoid this in the future can you please give me a bit of advice or maybe point me towards the right direction (tutorials, a rule of thumb, etc)? P.S add an answer to the post so I can mark it

Comment: there are a lot of great tutorials, maybe try Grant Abbitt's, it's a nice mix of modeling, texturing, animation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your face is made of a huge ngon, if the ngon is not completely flat it tends to creates artifacts like the ones we see when you smooth, because of the stretched triangles that compose it. So you need to correct the topology and work with quads as much as possible, sometimes tris... ngons are ok if they don't cause any problem.

For iphones see answers [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139912/how-to-add-extra-loop-cuts-without-affecting-subsurf) and [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112612/how-to-dig-an-elliptical-hole-in-blender-iphone) for example.